# Is there a proper way to constrain subviews of a UIScrollView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm having a difficult time getting any of my subviews to show up, even though when I check out the view UI hierarchy section of my debugger all subviews appear and are correctly constrained (to my knowledge).

My `UIScrollView` is `Home.PlayWorkout` and its subviews are `Home.WorkoutInstruction` (also `UIScrollView`'s)

[image]

So, for each subview I'm constraining the top, trailing, leading, and height properties, but nothing shows up at all. I get a blank screen that looks like this (I highlighted the parent `UIScrollView` green to demo that it's indeed there):

[image]

Comment: So you have constraints properly set for all size classes? Like you do not have constraints for wRegular hRegular only but are also using the app on a device that don't use that size class such as an iPhone.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html

Comment: I'm not quite sure - I'm pretty new to ios. I'm using NSLayoutConstraint() objects to layout each view and setting each element's translateAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = false. I can post code if that would help, but it's a bit obfuscated with stuff like data parsing and stuff like that, so I figured it might be more straightforward without it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So in the storyboard if you select a vc you should see at the bottom of the screen something like `wAny hAny`. "Any" represents a general size class even though no device actually falls into this class. If you only have contraints set for `wAny hAny` then things can possibly not be displayed exactly how they appear in the story board. Read the link I sent you, it explains the size class for every device type. For iphone 5 its `wCompact hRegular` in portrait. Try setting the constraints for that size class. If it works let me know :) Test things out with preview in xcode.

Comment: You can test things out with preview in xcode and use different devices such as iPad or iPhone. Do the subview show up on devices with larger screens?

Comment: @boidkan I'll definitely check out the link. I'm actually doing it 100% programmatically though and adding it to an existing view controller using a UITapGestureRecognizer. I appreciate the help though and I'll write back if I'm able to solve it using the information in your link!